# Is it natural to say "Ok, I will"?

Tags: grammar

To me it seems perfectly fine, but I heard from a native speaker that it does not sound natural.

For example:

> — Will you please send the assets by tomorrow?
>
> — Ok I will.

Does this sound natural?

What are other more "natural" alternatives than "Sure I will", "Yes I will", and "Ok"?

Comment: Here are four to be going on with:- 'Okay then' - 'No problem' - 'I'm onto it' - 'Consider it done', and many more.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK What about my main question? does it sound natural to you?

Comment: "OK, I will" sounds fine, and natural, to me.

Comment: Yes, it sounds okay to me.

Comment: I say this all the time in response to questions like in your example.  It's perfectly natural.  It would be interesting to know more about your native speaker:  how old are they, what region did they grow up in, what's their level of education, what's their ethnicity, etc.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Great! Do you mind putting your answers together and post it as an answer, so that I can accept it? it will be better if you could arrange some more possible examples.

Comment: @Jim thanks for your answer Jim! the native speaker is from US, and I think he learned linguistics and he's a bit pedantic. you know sometimes we use phrases that are technically wrong in grammar. so I was figuring this was such case...

Comment: I do  know that we sometimes use phrases that are technically wrong in grammar, but I can't see how this is one of them.  "OK" is used for acquiescing to a request, and "I will" is the elided form of "I will do as you asked." All perfectly grammatical.

Comment: @Jim I guessed so too! Thanks for your information. Just a side question.. is it correct to say "such case" and not "such a case" in my previous comment?

Comment: No, it needs to be "such ***a*** case"

Comment: It is fine to say this.  "Ok, I will ( send that.). That is the complete sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Okay, will do.*

This is very effective (in the U.S.) to convey cooperativeness and a positive attitude.

Answer (score 2):

Saying ok I will is completely fine and perfectly natural to me. I'm a senior citizen, make note that everyone speaks a little differently especially depending on where you are. I noticed that my grammar can change to slightly more proper if I'm at a doctors office for example.